# 'people far from business and politics'

Tags: expressions, phrase-choice

Do native English speakers use any idiomatic expression for 'far from a specific topic or an area of activities'?

> Some ratings are based on summarizing opinions of people far from business and politics.

Comment: Sometime you might hear the expression "outside one's area of expertise", for example: _Most importantly, do not allow yourself to be drawn into offering opinions on areas outside of your area of expertise._ (from _The Handbook of Professional and Ethical Practice for Psychologists_, 2004, p. 102)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your quote, the expression is already idiomatic, because the distance being judged is not one of length, but experience or knowledge.

In that context, 'far from' becomes more like 'with no experience or direct knowledge of'

It, of course, does not mean they have never travelled within 5 miles of any business or political establishment; so is entirely reliant on the juxtaposition of distance with experience, the distance being mental not physical.

I can't find any direct reference, but off the top of my head, synonyms could be (increasing in pejorative meaning yet using as many prepositions as I can think of)
far removed from
distanced from
inexperienced in
unconnected with
not influenced by
with little knowledge of
*(very colloquial)* clueless about

Comment: "Far removed from" could work here as well, with no pejorative connotations.

Comment: Sure: will add (just in case this ends up being some kind of reference list;-) btw, the pejorative increment happened somewhat accidentally; I felt it worth mentioning post-facto